# found this code hiding underneath my html after validation. any harm?

Tags: html, validation, xhtml

i am doing html validation and found one error . the below code is hiding underneath my html. any harm? how to remove it? is it due to the host?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-5263515-4']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.3eeweb.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html validation isnt really reliable.
Are you using Dreamweaver for something?

Google Analytics code would be 100% safe. Just make sure you put it in the correct spot which is normally at the footer.

Comment: Yes it is.
Just put it before `</body>` on your page.

Comment: well, i can't even find that block of code inside my html..i did register webmaster thou..i think this might be automated?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for Website Tracking with [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Answer (score 1):

This code is from Google Analytics